# Delay response until all queries finished

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, node-async

My db contains projects and phases. Projects can have multiple phases. The models are similar to these:

Phase:

```
var phaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  project: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' }
});
```

Project:

```
var projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : { type: String }
});
```

Currently I'm using the following approach to retrieve the phases for each project:

```
var calls = [];
var projects = _.each(projects, function (p) {
  calls.push(function (callback) {
    req.app.db.models.Phase.find({ project: p._id }, function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        p.phases = doc;
        callback();
      }
    });
  })
});

async.parallel(calls, function (err) {
  workflow.outcome.projects = projects;
  return workflow.emit('response');
});
```

As you can see I'm not passing anything to `callback()` just (ab)using [async's](https://github.com/caolan/async) `parallel` to wait with the response until the lookup finishes.

Alternatively I could pass the phase object to the callback but then in `parallel` I should iterate over phase and over projects to find the appropriate project for the current phase.

Am I falling into a common pitfall with this design and for some reason it would be better to iterate over the projects and the phases again, or I should take a completely different approach?

Comment: There is something missing here ( or I am missing something ). The `async.parallel()` call is fine and will run all tasks in the array before executing the final callback argument. What is `p.phases = doc` meant to be doing? It would only be assigining the current response on every task execution, and therefore "overwriting" on every task execution. It just seems a bit bizarre to call `.find()` and not actually keep all the results. Why not pass to the callback for each task? i.e `callback(err,doc)` and then get the array of responses in the parallel callback `function(err,results)`?

Comment: Also what is the point of the operation in the first place? ( that's what seems to be missing in explanation ), Your words *"...find the appropriate project for the current phase.."*. That seems to imply that maybe one of the responses means something? Just fishing as the intent is not clear. There probably is a better approach if you describe what this is means to do.

Comment: Surely far less hackish would be to do one query with `$in` as a list of all the `_id` values for each project in the array. The resulting response could then just be matched against the input array and "map" in the results, if you really needed to that is. Seems to me that one query would run rings around using up connection resources for each array member.

Comment: On reflection, I'm probably ranting. Explained in an answer which should cover what I think you are asking really.

Comment: `p.phases = doc` assigns the current response on every task execution to the current `p`, and it won't "overwrite" any previous values since in every task execution there is a different p. Task executions are created inside and `_.each`, for every p in projects. The point of each task operation is to find the phase for the current project `p` (there is a typo in the question, I wrote that I need to find projects for every phase which is obviously not what I'm doing).

Comment: Yes I gathered it was rather *"phases for each project"*, which would imply an array rather than an assignment. Anyhow, I eventually thought the commentary was better placed in an answer.

Comment: Okay, reading my question again, this part: _Alternatively I could pass the phase object to the callback but then in parallel I should iterate over phase and over projects to find the appropriate project for the current phase_ refers to an alternative solution where I would pass the result of `find` to `callback`. In that case in `parallel` I would have an array of phases without projects, so I would need another operation to find the matching project for each phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think in this case you would be better of running one query to match all the potential results. For the "test" query you would issue all the `_id` values as an [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) clause, then just do some matching on the results to your source array to assign the match(ed) document(s):

### Matching all at once

```js
// Make a hash from the source for ease of matching
var pHash = {};
_.each(projects,function(p) {
    pHash[p._id.toString()] = p;        
});

// Run the find with $in
req.app.db.models.Phase.find({ "project": { "$in": _.keys(pHash) } },function(err,response) {
       _.each(response,function(r) {
           // Assign phases array if not already there
           if (!phash[r.project.toString()].hasOwnProperty("phases")
               pHash[r.project.toString()].phases = [];
           // Append to array of phases
           pHash[r.project.toString()].phases.push(r)
       });

       // Now return the altered hash as orginal array
       projects = _.mapObject(pHash,function(val,key) {
           return val;
       });

});
```

Also adding like you say *"projects can have multiple phases"*, so the logic would be an "array" rather than an assignment of a single value.

---

### More efficient $lookup

On the other hand, if you have MongoDB 3.2 available, then the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operator seems to be for you. In this case you would just be working with the `Projects` model, but doing the `$lookup` on the `"phases" **collection**. With "collection" being the operative term here, since it is a server side operation that therefore only knows about collections and not the application "models":

```js
// BTW all models are permanently registered with mongoose

mongoose.model("Project").aggregate(
    [
        // Whatever your match conditions were for getting the project list
        { "$match": { .. } },

        // This actually does the "join" (but really a "lookup")
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "phases",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "project",
            "as": "phases"
        }}
    ],function(err,projects) {
        // Now all projects have an array containing any matched phase
        // or an empty array. Just like a "left join"
    })
);
```

That would be the most efficient way to handle this since all the work is done on the server.

So what you seem to be asking here is basically the "reverse case" of `.populate()` where instead of holding the "phases" as references on the "project" object the reference to the project is instead listed in the "phase".

In that case, either form of "lookup" should be what you are looking for. Either where you emulate that join via the `$in` and "mapping" stage, or directly using the aggregation framework `$lookup` operator.

Either way, this reduces the server contact down to "one" operation, where as your current approach is going to create a lot of connections and each up a fair amount of resources. Also no need to *"Wait for all responses"*. I'd wager that both were much faster as well.

Comment: This isn't what I expected because I thought I should optimize my code on the `async` side. However, you pointed out that there is much more room for optimization on mongo level and your solution also covers what I really asked. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @akoskm As noted, there really should be no need to manage multiple async calls for what you want to do, which is basically a lookup of the related information. Don't forget to vote. :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't figure out (`$lookup`) how to find all the information that I need one query - which automatically eliminates the need for multiple callbacks.

Comment: And what do you mean by _BTW all models are permanently registered with mongoose_, I think you're referring to my `req.app.db.models.Phase` access of the schema. I was following the conventions in https://github.com/jedireza/drywall, for instance: https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/blob/master/schema/Category.js where the schema is registered on `app.db.model('Category', categorySchema);` where `app.db` is https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/blob/master/app.js#L27 What do you think about this approach?

Comment: @akoskm Just like in the listing, the model is registered with `mongoose` as in: `var mongoose = require('mongoose')`; mongoose.model('Project')`. Any such subsequent call like that ( after you initially did your assignment of schema ) will actually retrieve the model. All your `ap.db` is doing is pointing to an instance of `mongoose`. You don't need it. Just `var mongoose = require('mongoose')` in every module. It does not load multiple times, but only once.